# D3 / JavaScript find nearest element from mouse position

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I am trying to show the nearest data point and its text when you hover over path element (in pink color in the example) using D3 / Javascript.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkcsrt7p/

I tried searching for examples but I haven't got anything that can give me the nearest data point to the mouse position. Has anyone tried similar functionality before?

Code so far:

```
d3.selectAll("g text.label")
  .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    tooltip.transition().duration(200)
      .style('opacity', .9)
    var toolTipText = "<span>" + this.textContent + "</span>";
    tooltip.html(toolTipText)
      .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
      .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function (d) {
    tooltip.transition().duration(200)
      .style('opacity', 0);
    tooltip.html("");
  })

d3.selectAll("path")
  .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    var elements = document.elementsFromPoint(d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY);
    console.log(elements);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function (d) {

  })
```

Comment: Would't you just traverse through the nodes and check the point distance between the mouse and the current point and return the point with the shortest distance?

Comment: I tried getting nearest nodes using document.elementsFromPoint but it does not include text / Polygon when I hover over the path element. It includes [path, svg, div#svgContainer, body, html].

Comment: You can use `elements[1].querySelectorAll('polygon')` to get your points.

Comment: that's fine but how can I get the nearest polygon from the mouse position? Do I need to check their x and y position to determine the nearest polygon?

Comment: Yes. I tried the following in a fork: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/xbywvk68/ using `polygon.getBBox()` (bounding box) and line distance.

Comment: looks really good - I will have a look. Thank you.

Comment: check out the [following link](https://gangulabs.github.io/d3-svg-path-editor/) with shows a working example. [this](https://github.com/cdaringe/d3-svg-path-editor) is the originals source code for this. This was created by referring [the gist](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/8027637) by mbostock